# Exception Property [Category] does not exist on this collection instance. al mostrar datos en la vista en una relacion uno a muchos

Tags: laravel, eloquent, blade

Hola estoy trabajando en una vista que trae datos desde una consulta basada en una relacion uno a muchos, desde el controlador la variable trae datos de la tabla intermedia, pero la vista no logra acceder a la relacion y devuelve la exception:

```
Exception Property [Category] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Modelos:
-ProductCategory

```
public function Product(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'id');
    }
```

-Product

```
public function ProductCategory(){

    return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class,'id');
}
```

-Brands

```
 public function ProductCategory(){

    return $this->hasMany(ProductCategory::class,'id');
}
```

Controlador:

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $p = Product::find($id);
   
    $pc =  ProductCategory::where('brands_id', $id)->with('Product')->get();
    return view('productos.show', compact('pc','pc'));
}
```

vista

```
 @foreach($pc as $p)
    @foreach($p->Product as $v) 
     <td>{{$v->nombre}}</td
```

El dd de la variable pc trae:

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "products_id" => 2
    "brands_id" => 1
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
```

Solucionado el Foreach de la vista esta bien, habia un problema de las relaciones que estaban invertidas

Comment: Asi es y poder mostrar el nombre de los productos

Comment: Modifique a esto: @foreach($pc as $p)  @foreach($p->Product as $v)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$v->nombre}}</td>
    </tr> y me devuelve un: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: solo hay 1 dato en cada tabla

Comment: estoy poniendo el foreach para llenar una tabla para mostrar todos los Products de una ProductCategory

Comment: Lo pude solucionar tenia mal hechas las relaciones y ahora veo los datos, el problema es que al recorrer dos foreach los datos de la tabla en la base llegan en orden y no los correspondientes a las categorias

Comment: Entonces considera publicar tu solución para que la pregunta no quede sin solución

Comment: La solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta

Comment: Solucionado el Foreach de la vista esta bien, habia un problema de las relaciones que estaban invertidas